# JAR runnable file cannot execute in other PC

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have write a small Java program using SWT GUI which search a given word inside a given text file, but when I run the program in Eclipse it works well, and if I exported it as a runnable jar file, in my PC it works well, but when I run it in other PC’s then it doesn’t work (cannot run, dosen't luanch the frame)… and also the same Java JDK (1.7) is installed in both my and other PC’s. Before JDK1.7 when I execute the runnable jar file it works well in all other PC’s, but now any jar file cannot run in other PC’s, but only in my PC….
Now if someone knows what the problem is, please suggest me how to solve.

Note: I exported the jar file in three options, but the result for all was the same.

1. Extract required libraries into generated JAR
2. Package required libraries into generated JAR
3. Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to generated JAR

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you unjar the file, are all required classes included? How do you include the SWT jars?

Comment: Can you show us the .jar?

Comment: I unjared the file, there was all the file and libraries the needed in side the jar file, and i used two ways included the libraries 1. by adding the  external archieve. 2. by copying and paste the jar file into project and then added to build path, no one solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the problem with "JAR runnable file cannot execute in other PC", the problem was with SWT library which cannot executed in 64bit JVM, my machine is 32bit.
It throws the exception below:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to Build path -> configure Build path -> Order and export

and check your jar file.

after that, try to create new runnable jar file.